# How do I get the referenced table name involved in a foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys

I have a Foreign key on my database like:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Table2] FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES [Table2]([Id])
```

So wrote a small c# program to get the `ForeignKeys` from my database shown below:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
{

    connection.Open();
    DataTable getSchema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
    foreach (DataRow tableRow in getSchema.Rows)
    {
        String tableName = tableRow.Field<String>("TABLE_NAME");
        DataTable fKeys = connection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys", new[] { database, "dbo", tableName });
        foreach (DataRow keys in fKeys.Rows)
        {
            String tName = key.Field<String>("table_name");
        }

     }
}
```

This returns the name of the `Table` the Foreign key is on `(Table1)` but I cannot get the other name of the other table this foreign key references `(Table2)`.

Is it possible to get the name of the other table in the foreign key constraint using c#?

Comment: I don't think you can use `GetSchema` in order to extract the info you want. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is all you can get for *Foreign Keys* and the referenced table is not part of it.

Comment: @Servy This is not a duplicate question. The answer makes use of the same SQL command, but the question is different. This is asking about C# the other is SQL. How can that be a duplicate question?